# HTML/CSS: What is preventing the body from covering the whole page?

Tags: html, css, dom, css-float, sidebar

This is a homework assignment. My initial goal is to get a side bar on the right. I have the body, then a container div called "wrap" to hold the entire contents of the body. If I create another div for the side bar at the end of this "wrap" container div, the sidebar should be placed on the outside and I should be able to float it to the right. This isn't happening for me and I can't figure out why.

Edit: Relevant code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sartre’s List</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,700,300italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
    <div class="top">
    <header>
            <h1><a href="index.html">Sartre’s List</a></h1>
            <h2>Better-Dressed People</h2>
            <nav>
                    <a href="#">Women’s</a>
                    <a href="#">Men’s</a>
                    <a href="#">On the Street</a>
                    <a href="#">The Catwalk</a>
                    <a href="#">AdWatch</a>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
            </nav>
    </header>
</div>
    <div class="item">
    <article>
            <h3>11/12/13</h3>
            <h2><a href="#">On the Street in Brooklyn</a></h2>
            <img src="img/fashion_photo.jpeg">
            <p> article content</a></h4>
    </article>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    <article>
            <h3>11/11/13</h3>
            <h2><a href="#">Vintage in Vogue</a></h2>
            <img src="img/fashion_photo2.jpeg">
            <p> Article Content</p>
            <h4><a href="#">Continues...</a></h4>
    </article>
</div>
    <footer>
            <nav>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                    |
                    <a href="#">Women’s</a>
                    |
                    <a href="#">Men’s</a>
                    |
                    <a href="#">On the Street</a>
                    |
                    <a href="#">The Catwalk</a>
                    |
                    <a href="#">AdWatch</a>
                    |
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                    |
                    <a href="#">Tips</a>
            </nav>
            <p>&copy; 2013 Valet Industries, Inc.</p>
    </footer>
</div>
<div id="sidebarWrap">
<div class="sidebar">About us</div>
<div class="sidebar">Ad</div>
<div class="sidebar">Popular Posts</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 3em;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #444;
    border-left: 6px solid #DDD;
    float: left;

}

a {
    color: #D00;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
}
a:hover {
    color: #A00;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1, h2 {
display: inline;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: normal;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: gray;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 0;
}
h2 a {
    color: inherit;
}
h2 a:hover {
    color: #D00;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #CCC;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h4 {
    text-align: right;
}

img {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}


header h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}

footer {
    color: #BBB;
 }

 header nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    margin: 0;
    color: #DDD;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #EEE;
    background: black;
    padding: 10px;
    height: ;
 }  
  header nav a:hover {
    color: gray;
    border-bottom-color: #BBB;
}

article {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
    margin: 3em 0;
    padding-bottom: 1.5em;
}
article p:first-letter {
    float: left;
    font-size: 6em;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #DDD;
    margin: -.1em .1em 0 -.1em;
}


#wrap {
    width: 750;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 40em;
}

#sidebarWrap {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
}

.top {
    float: top;
}
.item {
    float: left;
}
.sidebar {
    float: right;
```

When I look at this in Chrome, the body shows that it is not covering the entire page. The margin is set to 0 and there is only padding/border on the left side. If anyone can help me figure out why the body is not covering the whole page I would appreciate it very much. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your post instead of just providing pastebin links.

Comment: Will do, going to edit now

Comment: @MarkAmery I have edited my question. Is it now acceptable?

Comment: Possibly, although there's quite a large amount of code here and the issue could be demonstrated with a tiny, easily readable amount. These kind of large code dumps are usually discouraged because a) it's more work for answerers to figure out what's going on compared to a simple toy case, and b) future visitors are unlikely to get much benefit, since they can't see at a glance if your case is the same as theirs. Fiddling with your code, the `float:left` on the body seems to cause your problem, though I'm not enough of a CSS wizard to know quite how floats and widths interact.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I got rid of the body float and I'm now able to manipulate the page how I want!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
body { 
  height:100%;
  width:100%;  
}
```

Depending on your design, this might work, might not.

Comment: This actually helped, not sure why it's not floating left anymore though.

Comment: but why you are floating the body ?

Comment: I just removed it, I'm not just floating the container div. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a width:100% style rule to body.

Comment: Border defaults to nothing. Size defaults to the size of the containing elements. Margin defaults to 8px (at least in Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

`html,body
    min-height: 100%
    overflow:scroll //Legendary Hack`

use 'overflow:scroll' worked for me!